# Wordpress echo php value in shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to echo a variable in the function do shortcode but it is not outputting the variable in the shortcode.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $productids = the_field('project_products'); echo do_shortcode("[products ids=\"$productids\"]")?>
```

But when I output the variable `$productids` out the function `do_shortcode` it does output the right numbers.

I dont know why it is not working in the `do_shortcode` function.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please post the function (products) generating the shortcode.

Comment: You need to concatenate the php variable, as the way you have it now this is just a string. Like this - echo do_shortcode("[products ids=\"".$productids."\"]")